# Apache - is it necessary run Apache as a user other than the System user

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, php

The Apache document says:

> By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system user (the LocalSystem account). The LocalSystem account has no privileges to your network via any Windows-secured mechanism, including the file system, named pipes, DCOM, or secure RPC. It has, however, wide privileges locally.
>
> Never grant any network privileges to the LocalSystem account! If you need Apache to be able to access network resources, create a separate account for Apache as noted below.

I just using the Apache to run my website, is it necessary run Apache as a user other than the System user? What's mean about "using Apache to access network resources"

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Sorry, I forget it, it's windows server 2008 R2

Comment: *"Is it necessary run Apache as a user other than the System user?"* - the answer is likely "No".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're running Apache on some version of Windows.

"Using Apache to access network resources" here would mean, for example, having the files of your website on a NAS device that is sharing them (using SMB = the Windows disk sharing protocol) to the Windows system that is running Apache.